# Plotting 2D image of functions of several variables

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, and I would like to plot the region $f([0,1]^4)$. Writing $f_1(s,t,u,v)$ and $f_2(s,t,u,v)$ for each coordinate of the output I tried using *Mathematica*'s parametric plotter:

```
ParametricPlot[{f1[s,t,u,v], f2[s,t,u,v]} , {s,0,1}, {t,0,1}, {u,0,1}, {v,0,1}]
```

This failed because *Mathematica* seems to only support parametric plotting in (at most) two parameters. Does anyone know of a work around?

For the sake of having a working example, an abbreviated example of my functions is:

```
f1[s_,t_,u_,v_]:=(s+1/s)(t+1/t)Cos[\[Pi] u/4]Cos[\[Pi] v/4];
f2[s_,t_,u_,v_]:=(s+1/s)(t-1/t)Cos[\[Pi] u/4]Sin[\[Pi] v/4];
```

Comment: Related: [13378](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13378/parametric-regions)

Answer (score 6):

The functions are

```
f1[s_, t_, u_, v_] := (s + 1/s) (t + 1/t) Cos[Pi u/4] Cos[Pi v/4]
f2[s_, t_, u_, v_] := (s + 1/s) (t - 1/t) Cos[Pi u/4] Sin[Pi v/4]
```

One obvious feature is that the term `(s + 1/s) Cos[Pi u/4]` is common to both functions, so changing `s` and `u` will just scale the region defined by `t` and `v`. The range of values for the term `(s + 1/s) Cos[Pi u/4]` is:

```
(s + 1/s) Cos[Pi u/4] /. s | u -> Interval[{0, 1}]
```

> ```
> Interval[{1/Sqrt[2], Infinity}]
> ```

Let's call that term `z` and define:

```
g1[z_, t_, v_] := z (t + 1/t) Cos[Pi v/4]
g2[z_, t_, v_] := z (t - 1/t) Sin[Pi v/4]
```

Now we can plot the region defined by `t` and `v` with a few values of `z`:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Table[{g1[z, t, v], g2[z, t, v]}, {z, {1/Sqrt[2], 2, 4}}]
 , {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, Axes -> False, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

The outermost region is the one with `z = 1/Sqrt[2]`, so we can just set that as a fixed value and plot the region as:

```
ParametricPlot[{g1[1/Sqrt[2], t, v], g2[1/Sqrt[2], t, v]}, {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 Axes -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: a big +1 for using some common sense. (I was too lazy to do it:)

Answer (score 4):

I think this should work:

```
f1[s_,t_,u_,v_]:=(s+1/s)(t+1/t)Cos[\[Pi] u/4]Cos[\[Pi] v/4];
f2[s_,t_,u_,v_]:=(s+1/s)(t-1/t)Cos[\[Pi] u/4]Sin[\[Pi] v/4];

data=Partition[Flatten[
    Table[{f1[s,t,u,v],f2[s,t,u,v]},{s,0.1,1,0.05},{t,0.1,1,0.05},{u,0,1,0.05},{v,0,1,0.05}]
],2];
Dimensions@data

ListPlot@data
SmoothDensityHistogram@data
```

[image: List Plot]
[image: SmoothDensity Histogram]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could plot it parametrically in 2 of the variables and use a slider to control the other two variables. For example

```
f1[s_, t_, u_, v_] := (s + 1/s) (t + 1/t) Cos[\[Pi] u/4] Cos[\[Pi] v/4];
f2[s_, t_, u_, v_] := (s + 1/s) (t \[Minus] 1/t) Cos[\[Pi] u/4] Sin[\[Pi] v/4];
Manipulate[
   ParametricPlot[{f1[s, t, u, v], f2[s, t, u, v]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 400}], {s, 0.001, 1}, {t, 0.001, 1}]
```

Or, somewhat easier to control is to place the two manually controlled vairables in a 2D controller (here the s and t variables are replaced by the two dimensions of the slider).

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{f1[s[[1]], s[[2]], u, v], f2[s[[1]], s[[2]], u, v]},
   {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}], {s, {0.001, 0.001}, {1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Or, you could control the u,v manually and have the plot be over the {s,t}.