# ParametricPlot with more than two parameters

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

This is a general question, and it actually was already asked before but for a case that was wisely solved (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26367/plotting-2d-image-of-functions-of-several-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1)). I'm going to give a naive example to be clear:

Let us suppose you have three different parametric functions (pairs): `{fx[a],fy[a]}`,`{gx[b],gy[b]}` and `{hx[c],hy[c]}` , with no common factor between them, etc. In particular, they come from `NDSolve` so they are actually `InterpolatingFunction`s with specific ranges, so we cannot handle the parameter regions of `a,b,c`.

For example:

`ParametricPlot[{{x^2, 2 x}, {y^3, 3 y}}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3}]`

gives no problem. But,

`ParametricPlot[{{x^2, 2 x}, {y^3, 3 y}, {z^4, 4 z}}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0,
   3}, {z, 0, 4}]`

does give the following message:

> ParametricPlot::nonopt: "Options expected (instead of {z,0,4}) beyond position 3 in ParametricPlot[{{x^2,2\ x},{y^3,3\ y},{z^4,4\ z}},{x,0,2},{y,0,3},{z,0,4}]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.

Is there a possibility to plot this case? Wolfram says in [this site](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/PlotParametricFunctions.html):

"The Wolfram Language can plot parametric functions in both two and three dimensions. Use a parametric plot when you can express the x and y or x,y, and z coordinates at each point on your curve as a function of one or more parameters."

Here "more parameters" means two?

Comment: Is that ok: `MapThread[
  ParametricPlot,
  {{{x^2, 2 x}, {y^3, 3 y}, {z^4, 4 z}}, {{x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0,
      4}}}
  ] // Show[#, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio] &`?

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, it worked! I didnt know `MapThread`. Now I will try to use it in my case.

Comment: `MapThread` is not necessary, it just makes it shorter than writing `Show[3 x ParametricPlot]`.

Comment: @Kuba Oh, yes. Thanks again.